# SQLite composite key for a table between two tables

Tags: sqlite, composite-key

I am trying to Connect Three tables. Two of them have Primary Keys which the Third is supposed to link to. I need this inbetween as it is linked to a fourth (but this Works fine). The code I have written is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMERS(
CUSTOMER_ID INT(10) NOT NULL, 
SURNAME CHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
NAME CHAR(50) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (CUSTOMER_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE WORKSHOP(
WORKSHOP_ID INT(10) NOT NULL,
NAME CHAR(100) NOT NULL, 
CHAIN_NAME CHAR(100),
CHAIN_ID INT(10),
CONTRACT_WORKSHOP CHAR(5) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (WORKSHOP_ID, CHAIN_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE CAR_DAMAGE(
DAMAGE_ID INT(10)  NOT NULL, 
CUSTOMER_ID INT(10) NOT NULL, 
DATE INT(20) NOT NULL, 
PLACE CHAR(128) NOT NULL,
WORKSHOP_ID INT(10) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (DAMAGE_ID, CUSTOMER_ID, WORKSHOP_ID, DATE, PLACE),
FOREIGN KEY (CUSTOMER_ID) REFERENCES CUSTOMERS (CUSTOMER_ID),
FOREIGN KEY (WORKSHOP_ID) REFERENCES WORKSHOP (WORKSHOP_ID)
);


INSERT INTO CUSTOMERS VALUES (1, "OLSEN", "TROND");
INSERT INTO CUSTOMERS VALUES (2, "JOHNSEN", "FELIX");
INSERT INTO CUSTOMERS VALUES (3, "SVINDAL", "AKSEL");
INSERT INTO CUSTOMERS VALUES (4, "BJORGEN", "MARIT");
INSERT INTO CUSTOMERS VALUES (5, "SVENDSON", "LISA");

INSERT INTO WORKSHOP VALUES (1, "BERTEL", "MOLLER", 1, "YES");
INSERT INTO WORKSHOP VALUES (2, "OLOF", "OLOF AUTO", 3, "NO");
INSERT INTO WORKSHOP VALUES (3, "J-AUTO", "MOLLER", 1, "YES");
INSERT INTO WORKSHOP VALUES (4, "SPEED", "BIRGER N. HAUG", 2, "YES");
INSERT INTO WORKSHOP VALUES (5, "RELAX AUTO", "MOLLER", 1, "YES");

INSERT INTO CAR_DAMAGE VALUES (1, 1, 10102008, "HELLERUD", 1);
INSERT INTO CAR_DAMAGE VALUES (2, 2, 14032015, "JAR", 2);
INSERT INTO CAR_DAMAGE VALUES (3, 3, 24052016, "LOMMEDALEN", 3);
INSERT INTO CAR_DAMAGE VALUES (4, 4, 31102017, "FLAKTVEIT", 4);
INSERT INTO CAR_DAMAGE VALUES (5, 5, 08062016, "STOCKHOLM", 5);
```

However, the problem occur as I get the error "foriegn key mismatch - CAR_DAMAGE referencing WORKSHOP.

I am using SQLite as I am forced to use it, given by my University.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Table `WORKSHOP` has a composite primary key `(WORKSHOP_ID, CHAIN_ID)`. Any foreign key referencing that table must be a composite foreign key, consisting of the same two fields. Hence, you would need to add `CHAIN_ID` to table `WORKSHOP` and change your foreign key declaration to something like:

```
FOREIGN KEY (WORKSHOP_ID, CHAIN_ID) REFERENCES WORKSHOP (WORKSHOP_ID, CHAIN_ID)
```

[More generally, your primary keys seem, based on the information given, more complex than they need to be: why not just have `WORKSHOP_ID` as PK of `WORKSHOP` and `DAMAGE_ID` as PK of `CAR_DAMAGE`? But maybe you have good reasons.]

Answer (score 0):

Thank you. This Method worked. Hence, when I proceeded, a New problem occured. The table CAR_DAMAGE is linked to a fourth table (Called DAMAGE_INFORMATION), With the code:

```
CREATE TABLE DAMAGE_INFORMATION(
DAMAGE_ID INT(10) NOT NULL, 
DAMAGE_TYPE CHAR(100) NOT NULL, 
DAMAGE_SIZE CHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
SPEND INT(10) NOT NULL, 
FOREIGN KEY (DAMAGE_ID) REFERENCES CAR_DAMAGE (DAMAGE_ID)
);
```

And I receive the same error as earlier, i.e. Foreign key mismatch "DAMAGE_INFORMATION" referencing "CAR_DAMAGE".

Is it not allowed to make a combination of 3 tables to 1, With different primary keys? The primary key of CAR_DAMAGE is:

PRIMARY KEY (DAMAGE_KEY, CUSTOMER_ID, WORKSHOP_ID)

Comment: If I answered your question, then please accept the answer. Thank you.

Comment: The issue you're seeing here is the same: mismatch between primary key and foreign key. Hard to say what the right foreign key declaration would be: what you write here as PK of CAR_DAMAGE is different from what was in the original question, and I don't know which is correct.